# how to toggle multiple dropdown with hover in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, reactstrap

I have multiple dropdowns and I want toggle when mouse hover of one of them but it does n't happen
link of my code:  [Link](http://%20https://jsfiddle.net/froya20/264vmLos/3)
I think, can send Id and have if for open dropdown but I want a good answer

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would really help if you could share your implementation so far with here. :)

Comment: @SiddAjmera jsfiddle.net/froya20/264vmLos/3  this my code

Comment: Are the dropdowns dynamically created?

Comment: @lomse isn't, create like a component

Comment: Can you share your code? It will make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @lomse yeah, I put a link in the question  [link](https//jsfiddle.net/froya20/264vmLos/3)

Comment: NavMenu.css file seems to be missing in the code that you shared

Comment: @lomse this file isn't important

Answer (score 0):

instead of having dropdownOpen flag you should have curDropdownID,it can be astring or a number,right now i assume it as string,so your state is like

```
 this.state = {
  collapsed: true ,
  curDropdownID: ''
};
```

you need to have isopen function to decide a menu is open or not as below:

```
isOpen=(id)=>{
    return this.state.curDropDownID===id
}
```

now you toggle menu function should take id as an argument to toggle menu like

```
 toggle(id) {    
   this.setState({curDropdownID:id})
}
```

and your UncontrolledDropdown should be rendered as

```
  <UncontrolledDropdown id="show" nav inNavbar onMouseOver={()=>{this.toggle('show')}} onMouseLeave={()=>{this.toggle('')}} isOpen={this.isOpen('show')} 
>
              <DropdownToggle nav caret className="text-dark">
                show
              </DropdownToggle>
              <DropdownMenu right>
                <DropdownItem href='/Search'>
                  Search
                </DropdownItem>
              </DropdownMenu>
          </UncontrolledDropdown>
```

Comment: Thank you, I did it, but isn't working, can you write this code in https://jsfiddle.net/ site and send